# Golang copy remote file to local folder using sftp golang library

Tags: networking, go, sftp

I got the code for create a file on remote host:

```
config := &ssh.ClientConfig{
    User:            "xx",
    HostKeyCallback: nil,
    Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
        ssh.Password("xx"),
    },
}

config.SetDefaults()
sshConn, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", "192.xx.1.xx:22", config)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer sshConn.Close()

client, err := sftp.NewClient(sshConn)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer client.Close()

file, err := client.Create("/www/hello9.txt")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer file.Close()

if _, err := file.Write([]byte("Hello world")); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

But is needed to copy a file from remote host to local host. How can I achieve this using the golang tools **github.com/pkg/sftp** and **golang.org/x/crypto/ssh** only?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do it using the `Open(path string)` and `WriteTo(w io.Writer)` methods from the sftp package (and of course you need an os.File or something similar to write to).

```
client, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", "192.x.x.x:22", sshConfig)
if err != nil {
    panic("Failed to dial: " + err.Error())
}
fmt.Println("Successfully connected to ssh server.")

// open an SFTP session over an existing ssh connection.
sftp, err := sftp.NewClient(client)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer sftp.Close()

srcPath := "/tmp/"
dstPath := "C:/temp/"
filename := "test.txt"

// Open the source file
srcFile, err := sftp.Open(srcPath + filename)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer srcFile.Close()

// Create the destination file
dstFile, err := os.Create(dstPath + filename)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer dstFile.Close()

// Copy the file
srcFile.WriteTo(dstFile)
```

Comment: I think that should be `dstFile, err := sftp.Create(dstPath + filename)`

Comment: Also  ```srcFile, err := sftp.Open(srcPath + filename)``` should be ```srcFile, err := os.Open(srcPath + filename)```

Comment: This is writing empty file

Comment: I just want to point out that the behavior of the nil HostKeyCallback has changed, so the config needs to change as well.  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44269142/golang-ssh-getting-must-specify-hoskeycallback-error-despite-setting-it-to-n