# GoLang ssh : Getting "Must specify HosKeyCallback" error despite setting it to nil

Tags: go, ssh

I am trying to connect to a remote server using GoLang. In the client configuration, apart from user and password, I set HostKeyCallback to nil so that it accepts every host

```
config := &ssh.ClientConfig{

        User: user,

        HostKeyCallback: nil,

        Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{

        publicKey,
    },
}
```

But I keep getting this error.

```
Failed to dial: ssh: must specify HostKeyCallback
```

How do I solve this ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The behavior of nil for HostKeyCallback was changed: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/19767

If you want to allow any host:

```
HostKeyCallback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey()
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer. But upon doing that, I see the following error,

    ssh: no common algorithm for key exchange; client offered: [xxxxxxxxxxx], server offered: [xxxxxxxx]

Comment: You may have to specify `KeyExchanges` documented here https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#Config the defaults it is using may not include any of the ones the server wants to use.

Answer (score 9):

Please heed the warning that comes with [ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey](https://github.com/golang/crypto/blob/eccd6366d1be82f8df741718dcdd586eea618221/ssh/client.go#L244-L246):

> ... It should not be used for production code.

So instead, consider enforcing SSH-key verification. It's actually not that difficult to implement:

```
// create human-readable SSH-key strings
func keyString(k ssh.PublicKey) string {
    return k.Type() + " " + base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(k.Marshal()) // e.g. "ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTY...."
}


func trustedHostKeyCallback(trustedKey string) ssh.HostKeyCallback {

    if trustedKey == "" {
        return func(_ string, _ net.Addr, k ssh.PublicKey) error {
            log.Printf("WARNING: SSH-key verification is *NOT* in effect: to fix, add this trustedKey: %q", keyString(k))
            return nil
        }
    }

    return func(_ string, _ net.Addr, k ssh.PublicKey) error {
        ks := keyString(k)
        if trustedKey != ks {
            return fmt.Errorf("SSH-key verification: expected %q but got %q", trustedKey, ks)
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

And to use:

```
// where `conf` is the main app config
sc := &ssh.ClientConfig{
    User:            conf.Username,
    Auth:            []ssh.AuthMethod{ssh.Password(conf.Password)},
    HostKeyCallback: trustedHostKeyCallback(conf.HostKey), // <- server-key goes here
    Timeout:         conf.Timeout,
}
```

if `conf.HostKey` is blank - it will still work - but will log a warning with the key-string to fill in to enable SSH-key verification.

Comment: Since this is an SSH key based authentication process, why is`&ssh.ClientConfig{}` setting a password-based authentication method `[]ssh.AuthMethod{ssh.Password(conf.Password)},`?

Comment: @pkaramol the question & answer are related to the `SSH` *client* verifying the *server's* identity (not the server verifying client creds).  The `HostKeyCallback` mechanism prevents [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) where credentials could be compromised - and is equivalent to the `ssh` command's `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file. In my example above I use a password-based credentials to the server - but any supported [ssh.AuthMethod](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#AuthMethod) may be used.

Comment: Have a question, `return func(_ string, remoteAdd net.Addr, k ssh.PublicKey)` how is the remoteAdd and k been passed? I checked the code of function dial. Didn't find how those are passed.

Comment: @michael the `ssh.Dial` call will lookup the `net.Addr` based on the `addr string` parameter. The key `k` is the server-side ssh-key returned via the dial SSH handshake. The callback simply verifies that the return (server-side) public key matches what we expect - and avoids any MITM attack.