# Running SCP via go exec.cmd

Tags: go, ssh, scp

I'm trying to run scp as command via golang's exec.cmd because the non-official implementations available for scp transfer did not work for me. Scp executes until it asks for the password and then I'm unable to write data to the stdin. Could it be possible that the stdin is redirected somewhere else?

```
var cmd *exec.Cmd
if m.IsDir() {
    cmd = exec.Command("scp", "-r", src, user+"@"+client.Host+":"+dest)
} else {
    cmd = exec.Command("scp", src, user+"@"+client.Host+":"+dest)
}

cmdWriter, err := cmd.StdinPipe()
if err != nil {
    return err
}

err = cmd.Start()

if cred.Typ() == "PW" {
    cmdWriter.Write( []byte(cred.Data()+"\n") )
} else {
    log.Println( "credential typ not supported" )
}

err = cmd.Wait()
log.Println( "done" )
return err
```

Setting cmd.Stdin to os.Stdin works but of course I have to manually enter the password which is not what I want. 
Or would you overall not recommend this way to run scp? I'm able to run simple SSH commands on the server (with "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"). Is there maybe a way to transfer binaries just via a SSH session?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See how you could implement scp: https://github.com/viant/toolbox/blob/master/ssh

Comment: Thanks but I was really looking for a simple solution. I already tried a few scp implementations.

Comment: Have you looked if `cmd` has some output? It does not necessarily return, as it may say wrong password or other things.

Comment: No writing to stdIn just has no effect. I even tried setting the input to os.stdin and then writing with os.stdin.write but it does not work. It only works if I enter it manually. I'm quite confident now that scp creates a subprocess that no longer uses the old pipe once it writes user@10.1.1.2' password to the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume you are on Linux. If you want to pass a password to `scp` from the command line, the best way is with `sshpass`. It should be available for install from the default package repositories on major Linux distros, just install it with `apt` or `yum`. The syntax is `sshpass -p [password] scp ...`

Here I spawn a `bash` session and pipe commands to it from the `StdinPipe`:

```
func main() { 
    cmd := exec.Command("bash")
    cmdWriter, _ := cmd.StdinPipe()
    cmd.Start()

    cmdString := fmt.Sprintf("sshpass -p %s scp -r %s %s@%s:%s", password, src, user, client, dest)

    cmdWriter.Write([]byte(cmdString + "\n"))
    cmdWriter.Write([]byte("exit"    + "\n"))

    cmd.Wait()
}
```

I have ignored errors and simplified your code a little for brevity.

---

However, the "github.com/pkg/sftp" package is much easier to use for file transfers like this. You can find a simple example of how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36786068/golang-copy-remote-file-to-local-folder-using-sftp-golang-library). Note that using `nil` for `HostKeyCallback` in the client config is deprecated - use `HostKeyCallback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey()` if you absolutely need to accept all host keys.

Comment: The github package looks like the best way to go. My software has to run with as few as dependencies possible so sshpass is not really an option. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

scp and ssh insist on reading the password from a tty (or psuedo tty)

stdin from a remote session is not this so it will not work

The standard go [golang.org/x/crypto/ssh](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh) package does support sending passwords so presumably has a work around.  [scp is implemented as a server that is invoked by ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37558853/how-scp-secure-copy-protocol-file-transfer-working) so probably extending the existing go ssh support would not be difficult

However, there is always an external program based workaround!  As  discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13955428/1153938), 
this involves using the `sshpass` program